# Add CSS class to JS script and Trigger With Button (night mode)

Tags: javascript, css

In my `header.php` template, I have a button that looks like this, in my stylesheet, I have the following CSS code and In an already enqueued JS file, I have this:

```js
function NightModeToggle(){
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("NightModeToggle");
}
```

```css
.NightModeToggle{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="NightModeToggle()">Dark</button>
```

I understand that it targets the body by using this line: `var element = document.body;`

**My question is**, how do I add additional targets so that I can change the background color and text color of the header and footer as well?

**I tried modifying the code into this (without result):**

```
var element = document.body;
var element = document.header;
var element = document.footer;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: _“how do I add additional targets so that I can change the background color and text color of the header and footer as well?”_ - ideally: You DON’T. Make _proper_ use of CSS selectors instead. If you want to format anything in your footer differently, based on the body having that particular class - then write a rule such as `body.NightModeToggle footer { … }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the structure of your HTML, you will need to target your other elements by using `document.querySelector()` and passing in the selector of the element you want to target, e.g.:

```
document.querySelector('footer') // If you use a <footer> tag
document.querySelector('#footer') // If you use e.g. <div id="footer">
document.querySelector('.footer') // If you use e.g. <div class="footer">
```

You can also use `document.querySelector('body')` instead of `document.body` to keep this approach consistent.

The reason `document.body` works is that `body` is a property of the `document` object that contains the contents of the document (the `<body>` tag). Similarly, `document.head` will return the content of the `<head>` tag in your HTML.

Comment: Okay, so all I do is add them by comma separating them? Example; `var element = document.querySelector('body'), document.querySelector('.footer'), document.querySelector('.header')` ?

Comment: Or do you mean like this: `var element = document.querySelector('body, .header, .footer')` ?

Comment: I got it :) Thanks so much.